# Error while parsing a datetime string with AM/PM in Python with time.strptime()

Tags: python, strptime

I'm getting a ValueError while parsing a time string with AM/PM in Python (3.7):

```
from time import strptime
strptime('19/06/2019 07:49:53 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

ValueError: unconverted data remains: PM
```

Why am I getting this error? The usage of `%I` and `%p` should enable the parsing of the AM/PM strings...

Comment: I am not facing any issue....`time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=19, tm_hour=19, tm_min=49, tm_sec=53, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=170, tm_isdst=-1)`

Comment: Thanks, it's an issue within Spyder. I run the code with IPython (which is used by Spyder, by the way...) and executed without any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working on my notebook, it looks like there's something else wrong.

I found [this](https://community.esri.com/thread/186384-arcpy-valueerror-unconverted-data-remains-pm) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-python/+bug/993096) searching your error, are you using arcpy or pynotify? Or any other library that could cause some conflicts?

Try to remove some import to localize if there's an error of this type

Comment: Thanks, I was using Spyder, and I could not reproduce the error with a new instance of IPython:
`In [1]: from time import strptime 
   ...: strptime('19/06/2019 07:49:53 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')                                    
Out[1]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=19, tm_hour=19, tm_min=49, tm_sec=53, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=170, tm_isdst=-1)
`